# How can I position a widget outside its container in a horizontal list with overflow in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, overflow

This is the [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST4Lg.png).

What I have tried:

```
Container(
        height: 60,
        child: ListView.separated(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 7,
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == 0) {
              return Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 60,
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 25,
                    bottom: -25,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                      ),
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                width: 60,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

This is what it looks like with [no horizontal scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQeJk.png) (less than 7 itemcount). This is what it looks like [with horizontal scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2BI8.png).

How to position the text outside of the stack while in front of the other widgets?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this works for you.

**Make sure overflow property of Stack = Overflow.visible else the overflowed part of the container gets clipped.**

```
height of child component=60
height of tooltip=20
positioned at bottom 0 placing it at bottom of the parent. Be careful with the sizes.
```

```
       return SizedBox(
      height: 70,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                //build your children here..
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            //build the tooltip here.
            Positioned(
              left: 25,
              bottom: 0,
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                ),
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                height: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: The text however has to be 'stuck' with the first widget in the listview. So when you scroll horizontally, the text follows the first widget and doesn't stay on the same place.

Comment: I have updated the code, you need to be careful with the sizes (height) of the container and your children as above. Let me know if it works.